# Oracle database

Tags: oracle-11g

what's the reason for Enterprise Manager is not able to connect to the database instance. ORA-28001: the password has expired (DBD ERROR: OCISessionBegin) error? How to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried changing your password, since it seems to have expired? That would seem like a logical place to start given that error message.

Comment: Reading error messages is for sissies. (+1)